# How can I scrape a excel file from a website and divide it in different parts?

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, python-requests

I need to create a solution that scrapes an excel file from a website in different parts of determined size.
Each part cannot be larger than 10MB and the file is of extension (.xls).

I'm able to write different parts of determined size but they are unusable with strange characters. I've tried to change the encoding but it's not that either...

A code sample:

```py
with open(file, 'wb') as f:
        for part in requests.get(website_link, stream=True).iter_content(chunk_size=10000):
             f.write(chunk)
             actual_size += 10000
             if actual_size + 10000 >= maximum_chunk_size:
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) or beautifulsoup4 parsing data it's more convenient than requests.

You can check the file size in runtime like this:

```py
import os

file_name = "/path/to/file"

file_stats = os.stat(file_name)
size_mb = file_stats.st_size / (1024 * 1024)  # in megabytes
size_kb = file_stats.st_size / 1024  # in kilobytes
size = file_stats.st_size  # bytes
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but this doesn't actually solve my issue. If you notice the original post, I'm trying to download a file and divide it while in download without losing data or having data damaged.